# $addFields $size property always returns zero - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have added $addFields property in aggregate query and $size of my documents always return 0. here are my tables and query

**table post:**

```
{
_id: 1,
text: 'some text',
}
```

**table comments:**

```
{
_id: 1,
text: 'comment text',
postId: 1
}
```

In aggregate i have the following

```
let aggregateDataQuery = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'comments',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'postId',
      as: 'numberOfComments',
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {numberOfComments: { $size: { $ifNull: ['$numberOfComments', []] } }},
  },
];
```

This query always result in **numberOfComments: 0**. I am sure that there are comments against **postId 1** but result is always zero. Any Idea what i'm missing here. thanks

Comment: please confirm postId is is object id type or not, if its string then convert it to objectId and try, or try adding a stage before lookup `{ $addFields: { _id: { $toString: "$_id" } } }` this will convert _id from objectid type to string

Comment: @turivishal that's ObjectId, I'm sure

Comment: `from: "posts"` collection name is wrong it should be comments collection name

Comment: sorry that's a typo in posted question. fixed it. please have a look agaiin

Comment: see the working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QrjqSgF8hN5), it should work, you need to just verify the connection with right database and collection name provided in `from`  it is correct or not.

Comment: it is exactly the same as I mentioned right ? strange. I wonder why it is not working on my side :(

Comment: out of the question, you don't need to use `$ifNull` operator because lookup will always return empty [] array if matching docs not found.

Comment: i think it is necessary otherwise where key is not present it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the clause `from` in `$lookup` stay of the collection than you want to join.
The starter collection must be `posts` collection.
So you should put `comments` instead `posts`.
The `$size` attribute not work because the join not join.

The code must be shomething like:

```
let aggregateDataQuery = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'comments',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'postId',
      as: 'numberOfComments',
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {numberOfComments: { $size: { $ifNull: ['$numberOfComments', []] } }},
  },
];
Posts.aggregate(aggregateDataQuery);
```

Comment: it is the same as question

Comment: it is changed after my answer